# Wait for localStorage update before dispatching fetch on useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I have a login page which returns a response , after which im setting a token in localStorage.

```
  const login = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const loginRes = await axios.post(`${url}/users/login/`, {
        username,
        password,
      });
      if (loginRes.data?.success === 1) {
        clearInputs();
        localStorage.setItem("user_id", loginRes.data.user_id);
        localStorage.setItem("token", loginRes.data.token);
        history.push("/home");
      } else {
        toast(loginRes.data?.data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      toast("An error occurred, please try again");
    }
  };
```

Im redirecting to home page after the response as:

```
    history.push("/home");
```

Inside home page im dispatching the action to get data from api,

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("token")) {
      history.push("/");
      return;
    }
    dispatch(getItems())
  }, [history, dispatch]);


export const getItems = () => {
    return async(dispatch) => {
        dispatch(fetchItemsRequest());
        await api.fetchItems().then(
            (res) => {
                dispatch(fetchSuccess(res.data.items));
            },
            (error) => {
                dispatch(fetchFailed(error));
            }
        );
    }
};
```

For the fetchItems() request, it requires the token from localStorage.

The problem is that when i click login , it is redirecting the home page and on the first load, token is passed as null , and no items are loaded in the home page as token is invalid. When i refresh the page, the data loads correctly. How do i wait for the localStorage to be set before the useEffect is called from home page?

Comment: Did you try `const token = localStorage.getItem("token");` and then add token in useEffect dependency?

Comment: yes @Nik ,  it doest work, and even if adding it as a dependency, the api will be called two times right? is it an optimal solution?

Comment: localStorage.setItem() is a synchronous operation, therefore it should be not the root cause of your problem...

Comment: ok thanks, figured out the error. @KonstantinSamarin

Comment: @MohitHarshan If your were able to find the solution, then can you please add it as the answer. It may help anyone stumbling upon similar issues.